# java.io.IOException: No groups found for user hive

Tags: hive, hiveql, usergroups

I have a simple test application to set session with Hive (simple authentication).

```
CliSessionState localSession = new CliSessionState(hiveConf)
localSession.setIsHiveServerQuery(true)
localSession.setCurrentDatabase("LOOM")
Driver driver = new Driver(hiveConf)
SessionState.start(localSession)   ///////////////////////////// 1.

List data = new ArrayList()
CommandProcessorResponse response = driver.run("SHOW TABLES") // 2. 
driver.getResults(data)
data.each {
    println "${it}"   // I skipped table list in log output
}

driver.close()
if (localSession != null) {
    localSession.close()       ///////////////////////////////// 3.
}
```

It works ok. I have got a list of tables in database `LOOM`. No errors or something. However, log output looks suspicious. There are a lot of lines like:

> org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation - Failed to get groups for user hive by java.io.IOException: No groups found for user hive

Does it indicate a problem in my code, hive settings or something? And what I should to do to rid of this messages?

---

The following is the app log. Rows with comments `1.`, `2.`, `3.`, produce respective line blocks:

`1.`

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation - hadoop login
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation - hadoop login commit
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation - Using user: "hive" with name hive
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation - User entry: "hive"
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation - Assuming keytab is managed externally since logged in from subject.
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation - UGI loginUser:hive (auth:SIMPLE)
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation - Failed to get groups for user hive by java.io.IOException: No groups found for user hive
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.DataTransferSaslUtil - DataTransferProtocol not using SaslPropertiesResolver, no QOP found in configuration for dfs.data.transfer.protection
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.DataTransferSaslUtil - DataTransferProtocol not using SaslPropertiesResolver, no QOP found in configuration for dfs.data.transfer.protection
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.DataTransferSaslUtil - DataTransferProtocol not using SaslPropertiesResolver, no QOP found in configuration for dfs.data.transfer.protection
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.DataTransferSaslUtil - DataTransferProtocol not using SaslPropertiesResolver, no QOP found in configuration for dfs.data.transfer.protection
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.DataTransferSaslUtil - DataTransferProtocol not using SaslPropertiesResolver, no QOP found in configuration for dfs.data.transfer.protection
```

`2.`

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation - Failed to get groups for user hive by java.io.IOException: No groups found for user hive
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation - Failed to get groups for user hive by java.io.IOException: No groups found for user hive
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.DataTransferSaslUtil - DataTransferProtocol not using SaslPropertiesResolver, no QOP found in configuration for dfs.data.transfer.protection
```

`3.`

```
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.DataTransferSaslUtil - DataTransferProtocol not using SaslPropertiesResolver, no QOP found in configuration for dfs.data.transfer.protection
```

---

***Update:***

- The log is a STDOUT/STDERR of this application I locally started in intellij idea (hadoop/hive installed on cluster I connect with *-site.xml's)
- I actually have a local user `hive` in group `hadoop` on the server.
- I set a breakpoint on `IOException` in intellij idea and switch on output of stacktrace. The following is a stacktrace for my specific exception instance:

  ```
  Breakpoint reached
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getGroups(Groups.java:210)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getGroupNames(UserGroupInformation.java:1721)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.HadoopDefaultAuthenticator.setConf(HadoopDefaultAuthenticator.java:64)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.ProxyUserAuthenticator.setConf(ProxyUserAuthenticator.java:47)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveUtils.getAuthenticator(HiveUtils.java:441)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.setupAuth(SessionState.java:759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.getAuthorizationMode(SessionState.java:1543)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.isAuthorizationModeV2(SessionState.java:1554)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.doAuthorization(Driver.java:635)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:510)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1219)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1260)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1156)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.processors.CommandProcessor$run.call(Unknown Source:-1)
  ```

---

***Update2:***
There are Hive security settings:

```
hadoop.security.authentication=simple
hive.server2.authentication=NONE

hadoop.security.group.mapping=org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback
hadoop.user.group.static.mapping.overrides=dr.who=;
```

Comment: Is that log issued client-side, or server-side? Do you really have a Linux user named `hive` on that server? Is that user defined as a local user, or as a LDAP  / Kerberos account mapped with SSSD or Centrify? If LDAP/K, how often does the auth service refresh its cache, and how long does that take (vs. the timeout used in the Hadoop lib)? BTW, do you use the default `JniBasedUnixGroupsNetgroupMappingWithFallback` method?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter - Thank you for the comment. I do not understand some of questions. I will expand my question.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter - I have expanded the question, However, I do not know about `JniBasedUnixGroupsNetgroupMappingWithFallback`

Comment: Any warning about "native libraries" not being available client-side? For the record, there's a "feature" that usually hits you only with Kerberos auth; some moron inserted client-side tests in the Hadoop code base to simulate things that should only occur server-side, especially GroupMapping, and on Windows you need a special Hadoop run-time stub to get these "native libs"...

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter - Actually, there is not Kerberos authentication, but I have found a `JniBasedUnixGroupsNetgroupMappingWithFallback` in HiveConf. I have expanded the question.

Comment: By coincidence, I was debugging a Spark-on-Windows install this afternoon, and noticed that same error message. In that case, Spark instanciates a `HiveMetastoreClient` which calls _(but why??)_ `UserGroupInformation.getGroups()` client-side, which finally calls `JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.getGroups()`, which raises an Exception, which is trapped and logged as WARN and ignored somehow. But that happens just once, on startup.

Comment: Anyway, if you want to hide the messages, why don't you tweak the log4j configuration file to (a) check the "priority" for each message type and (b) hide messages lower than ERROR from `org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation`?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter - Thank you for the comments. Actually there is no problem to hide error messages. I concern about this messages because of possible real problems under this hood.